# Conditional behavior based upon auth

Tags: smart-contract, authorization

Imagine a contract that does not `require_auth()` but instead has conditional behavior depending upon which auth is present.

```
if (<conditional that checks auth>) {
  // do stuff given auth from account A
} else {
  // do stuff given any other auth
}
```

What is an example of the conditional that checks auth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example: `has_auth(accountname)`

See: https://eosio.github.io/eosio.cdt/1.5.0/group__action.html#function-hasauth